# API Management - Single API for multiple Logic Apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-api-management

I have 5+ separate logic Apps that are called via HTTP Receive. Examples are:

GetUsers
GetLocations
GetCalls

etc.

I would like to expose the Logic Apps via API Management as individual operations on one API. Any samples online to show I can do that? Am I right to assume that I'll need a policy (url-rewrite, control flow)?

Any guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add Logic Apps as operations on an existing API by:

1. Creating a new operation (by default http post for a Logic App)
2. Defining the request/response that your Logic App will expect you to pass to it
3. Go to the 'backend' element in the designer and select the 'forms based editor' from the designer.
4. In the editor, select 'Azure resource' and then browse to the Logic App you wish to use - the is should be an http request/response based Logic App.
5. Add other Operations and connect them up for each Logic App you want to use.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for your help, Matt.