# Switching between logic apps in APIM

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, apim

I have a requirement that we have a custom url and it goes to a logic app within APIM with all the security in place etc.

We need to switch between two different logic apps in the backend. We also need to know if there is a command line we can execute to change the backend url (from one logic app url to another)

I cannot seem to find any documentation about this at the moment.

Or should I use another API and for that to switch between possibly two different apis (one for DEV and one for TEST)

[image]

Comment: I would use a combination of Backends for Logic Apps Urls, a Named Value for choose condition to set select the correct backend and modifying the Named Value with Azure ClI: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/apim/nv?view=azure-cli-latest#az-apim-nv-update

Comment: check this SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50775613/api-management-single-api-for-multiple-logic-apps